# Multilingual website without language component in the URL

Tags: seo, search-engines, multilingual

I'm working on a website for Canada which will have `French` and `English` versions. For `SEO` purposes, I would like to avoid using any language tag in `URLs` because I believe it will have more impact (e.g. `example.ca/products` better than `en.example.ca/products` or `example.ca/en/products`).

I believe this is technically possible because the2 languages are sufficiently different that the `URLs` won't be conflicting with one another (e.g. if you want a "product" page, it will be `/products` in English, and `/produits` in French so you know which language the `URL` is about).

Since [`Google` (and most likely others) doesn't rely on the `URL` (nor `HTML` tags) to determine the content language](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28307/value-of-the-html5-lang-attribute) I don't see any problems with search engines.

To make this possible I've thought about using a `cookie` distinct from the session cookie (e.g. `example.org_language`) with long term expiry (e.g. `N` years) that will memorize the language chosen by the user. That way when people visit the website with a new browser session, they get served the proper language.

I have already given up on users being able to switch one page from `English` to `French`: when people will chose `English` or `French` from the menu they will be redirected to the corresponding version of the home page.

**Do you foresee any problems with not using a `language` component in the `URL` (whether domain or path)?** (*as long as one makes sure `URLS` don't conflict*).

Comment: In your question alone: *version*, *impact*, *determine* (excl. accents), *possible*, *different* (excl. accents), *(cookie)*, *session*, *long*, *page* and *menu* are all valid French words. The assumption that the languages won't overlap is risky. I'd quite easily see a potential usage for *page* and possibly *menu* in a URL.

Comment: True, although for my website (obviously you couldn't have figured out as I didn't mention it) I am expecting `URLs` to be like phrases, so the combination of words will be unique per language. After posting my question I just realized that for new visitors coming to the home page from search engines, I will have no way of differentiating the 2 languages as the `URL` will be the same for both (i.e. `/`) and the user won't be sending the `language cookie` :( Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the proper way would be:

- when user accesses site, get his language from browser using javascirpt
- present the user with what you've found, askig to confirm. than save to session.
- when the language is set in the session, give back the content in the language, no matter what url the client is visiting
- google / bots etc. sould not interprete the javascript, they get what they requested via /products /produits ...

btw: if you f* around with products, you should take a look at "nopcommerce" it can take care of this several ways... altough it has its issues ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a $_SESSION or $_COOKIE var to store the language settings.
If you're doing a 2 lang site then you can create a language switcher that sets whichever var type you've used to store the set lang, and then reload the index page in that language, but in every case you'll have to choose a default language.

In consideration of returning users cookie would be better than session, but is susceptible to being disabled, so I would recommend using both with cookie being higher priority.

```
index.php
switch ($_REQUIRE['langvar']):
  case default:
  //load english content
  break;
  case 'french':
  //load french content
  break;

langswitch.php
if ($_REQUIRE['langvar']=='en') {
  $_SESSION['langvar'] = 'fr';
} else {
  $_SESSION['langvar'] = 'en';
}
header('Location: index.php');
```